# When flying from New York to Australia, staying a month, then flying to New Zealand, and finally BACK to Australia - what kind of visa is required?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, australia, new-zealand

As American citizens, do we need two visas? A reentry visa for AU? How does this work? I've received conflicting information.

Answer (score 11):

As an American citizen you need an [Electronic Travel Authority](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au) to enter Australia. This serves in lieu of a visa and [allows you to visit](https://www.border.gov.au/help-text/eta/pages/en/information.aspx) as many times as you wish for one year after issuance, for up to three months per visit.

You do not need a visa or advance authorization to visit New Zealand under its [Visa Waiver](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/visa-waiver-countries) program.